# React/Redux controlling when a functional component renders

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm having this problem where my app updates too much. In my reducer I have an action of interest `checkTasks`. It doesn't do much, `checkTasks` goes through my list of current tasks, if any of them is expired, it removes them from the `tasks` array to place them into the `expiredTasks` array. My problem is that *most* of the time, `checkTasks` doesn't do anything, only sometimes. But every time `checkTasks` gets called my component gets rendered.

The `mapStateToProps` of my component looks like this:

```
const mapStateToProps = (_state) => {
    return {
        tasks: _state.tasksState
    }
}
```

and my component cares about 2 attributes from the state:

```
function Tasts({ tasksState: _tasksState}){
    ...
    return <>
        {renderExpired(_tasksState.expiredTasks)}
        {renderTasks(_tasksState.tasks)}
    </>
}
```

reducer

```
const reducer(_state = { tasks: [], expiredTasks: [] }, _action){
    const newState = { ..._state };
    ...
    case 'checkTasks':
            for (let i = newState.tasks.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                if (isExpired(newState.tasks[i])) {
                    newState.expiredTasks.push(newState.tasks.splice(i, 1)[0]);
                }
            }
        break;

    ...

    return newState;
}
```

What I'm noticing is that every time (once per second) the `checkTasks` action gets called, my component rerenders, even if practically the information in `expiredTasks` and `tasks` hasn't changed.

If I could change my `mapStateToProps` to something like

```
const mapStateToProps = (_state) => {
    return {
        tasks: _state.tasksState.tasks,
        expiredTasks: _state.tasksState.expiredTasks
    }
}
```

That would probably stop the constant refreshes, however, that seems to break all refreshes. Including tasks moving from one array to the other. I don't know if there's a way to tell redux *NOT* to trigger an update from the reducer, although that's probably an anti-pattern.
I'm also trying not to go trough `shouldComponentUpdate` given that evaluating whether I *should* update may require to check 2 object arrays against each other. Not triggering an update in the first place is much easier to handle than having to compare multiple arrays.

Comment: I think the best option is to modify whatever is calling that action-creator so much. Can you share you action-creator code and what's dispatching it?

Comment: @ChristopherNgo The action-creator is being called on a `setInterval(checkTasks, 1000)`. I understand that calling the action-creator every second is quite fast but is there no way of having recurrent actions and not updating components whose state isn't affected?

Comment: If you update your reducer-state, your component will always be re-rendered. What you can do to workaround this is modify your action-creator to determine whether you need to even dispatch an action. Share with us what your action-creator looks like

Comment: @ChristopherNgo at what state should I do that? in the interval callback itself? or can I *not* trigger an update from the reducer if I haven't changed anything?

Comment: You could do this check inside your action-creator logic itself. If you have a separate file for the action-creator, we would fix it there. We would condition in to dispatch, or not dispatch an action.

Comment: I just created an example of what you could do to solve this. :) Let me know if that works for you or if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you're using redux-thunk, you can really enhance the logic inside your action-creators. In this case, we're going to check to see if any tasks have expired by actually pulling your reducer data into our action-creator. Then applying very similar logic to what you already are doing, we will decide whether or not we will actually dispatch a new action.

```
const checkTasks = () => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
       const currentState = getState().yourReducer //your reducer key goes here. Returns its current state
       const expiredTasks = [] 

       for(let i = currentState.tasks.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
          if(isExpired(currentState.tasks[i]){ //remember to import your isEmpty() logic
               expiredTasks.push(currentState.tasks[i])
          }
       }

       if(expiredTasks.length > 0){
          dispatch({
             type: "checkTasks"
          })
       }

   }
}
```

If expiredTasks are empty then we won't send any action. No action, means no reducer update. Which means no component re-rendering.

Comment: Yeah it had just crossed my mind to use my sagas instead, but thank you for the example so I can give you credit!

Comment: Aw darn, well I'm sure you can apply pretty similar thought-process in your sagas implementation as well. :)